# how to change the page body div color in oblique theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, themes

I am trying to change the page content div color on a website that I am busy with. There is still a white space showing. Can someone advise as to how I change that sections color as well?

The theme uses SVG for diagonal sections. Not too clued up on that yet.

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to post the image yet.

Comment: Hi, does the div have an ID or class associated to it? If so, you should be able to use the ID or class in your own CSS to change the colour.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Hi. If you can please post a link to your site, we will be able to inspect your code and recommend you a solution.

Comment: [link](http://www.lifestylewithzee.co.za/wp)

Comment: @LauraClarke Yes it does have a div ID and class associated with it. The problem that I am facing is i am not sure what css to use as SVG is used for a diagnal section. The link to the current page i am having problems with is www.lifestylewithzee.co.za/wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find `<svg>` block, wich is inside `<div class="svg-container single-post-svg svg-block">...</div>` and over there to find a line `<path d="m 1925,0 0,150 -1925,0"/>` and set an attribute `fill`:

```
<path d="m 1925,0 0,150 -1925,0" fill="#1c1c1c"/>
```

It's a line 159 in HTML-code of resulting page.

The same action you need to do in `<div class="svg-container single-post-svg single-svg-bottom svg-block">...</div>` - add attribute `fill` to `<path>` (at line 184):

```
<path d="M 0,150 0,0 1925,0" fill="#1c1c1c"/>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This has worked. I edited it in the svg.php file

Comment: Only problem now is it has the #1c1c1c color above and below the header banner.

Comment: There is #333333 color over there

Comment: if I change that to #1c1c1c then because of the same color background <div class="svg-container single-post-svg svg-block"> does not show.